# How to extract regression coefficients from rasterstack in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am trying to fit a sine curve to a datasets and derived the coefficients. As this is my first time dealing with rasterstack, I am not sure how to print the coefficients. Does it possible to represent the coeff in term of raster layer?

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5) 
s <- stack( sapply(1:20, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3) )) ) 
s[1] <- NA 

time <- 1:nlayers(s) 

fun1 <- function(x) {
if (is.na(x[1])) {
NA
} else {
xcost<-cos(2*pi*time/24)
xsine<-sin(2*pi*time/24)
m = lm(x~xcost+xsine)
m$coefficients[2]
}
}

e1 <- calc(s, fun1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> e1[1,1]

NA 
> e1[1,2]

-1.810707 
> as.matrix(e1)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,]         NA -1.810707 -1.619409 -1.862829 -0.8928249
[2,] -4.4466952 -2.763915 -1.095858 -1.513916 -3.2462229
[3,] -0.5758164 -5.258762 -3.567696 -3.051799 -2.6290404
[4,] -2.9026886 -3.929019 -1.832168 -1.308834 -3.4590392
[5,] -3.6900736 -1.223912 -4.581699 -2.188620 -3.8804321
```

Comment: @Sofea Note that this will only get the second coefficient, which is the one associated with the cosine term. This isn't because anything is wrong with the answer, it is just that you only returned the cosine term in your function.

Comment: I assumed Sofea knew this, since the function was designed to return only the second (of a total of three) coefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much @DWin for the answer. I never aware that as.matrix(e1) is actually similar to e1[]. To plot it, i used plot(e1).  As nograpes pointed out, this is only for cosine term. How could I produce all three coefficients? Is it possible to do summary of the fit,     
xcost<-cos(2*pi*time/24)
xsine<-sin(2*pi*time/24)
m<-lm(x~xcost+xsine)
summary(m)
I also keep wondering where is actually all those m$fitted, resid been kept when we dealing with rasterstack.